# Maven : Apache Spark error when trying to "mvn package"

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I have installed spark 1.3.1 on local by downloading the zip and extracting it into my home repository so that I have it in here home/my-user-name/spark-1.3.1 .
The next thing is that I want to work using Java, and in order to it to work I have installed maven via this command :

```
$ sudo apt-get install maven
```

Then I checked the version with this command:

```
mvn -version
```

Which gave me this:

```
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-38-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Then the next thing is I wanted to create a java project using Maven from current depository Documents/ :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=projet -DartifactId=Indexing -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Which means that my pom.xml file is in repository Documents/projet/Indexing/
Here's is what I got in pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mif37.projet</groupId>
  <artifactId>Indexing</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IndexingMapReduce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

After that I included in the tag dependencies one more dependency to spark so I god this pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mif37.projet</groupId>
  <artifactId>Indexing</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IndexingMapReduce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And then I run the command-line from the repository where is pom.xml:

```
mvn package
```

But in the end here's what I got:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9:18.021s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun May 31 20:49:52 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/137M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Indexing: Could not resolve dependencies for project projet:Indexing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.3.1/spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar from central failed: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Anyone could point on where I do things wrong??
Thanks.

Comment: Here works fine. Can you run `mvn package -X` to enable full debug logging and update with the error?

Comment: are you behind a proxy? mvn will not respect system wide proxy settings, you must add them in ~/.m2/settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml and process is fine.  There is a firewall / connectivity issue - as noted by:

```
.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.3.1/spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar from central failed: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

You can verify for yourself by repeating your steps in an 'open' environment - e.g. at your home instead of work.